# Is it possible to use cassandra cqlsh copy command inside the python programme?

Tags: python, cassandra

Is it possible to execute Cassandra CQLSH copy command through a Python program. If yes, how?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I'm providing you a sample code about how we use cqlsh inside python. I guess, you'll can get some help from it but not interested to write the entire copy script for you.

```
 import subprocess

 host =  "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
 user = "cassandra"
 password = "cassandra"
 process = subprocess.Popen("cqlsh " + host + " -u " + user + " -p " + password, shell=True)
 exitCode = process.wait()
 if exitCode == 0:
     print "Job Done!"
 else:
     print "Still working!"
```

Comment: Where did you use the copy statement in the above snippet (as asked in the question)? These are more of configurational statements rather than to show how to use a copy statement.

Comment: I've provided a sample code for `cqlsh`inside the python program, those who know how to write python program, this sample is enough for them. Again if you want more hints to complete this, then put your copy command inside the `subprocess`, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code by using cassandra command for logging in, using keyspace and executing a query simultaneously in a single command.

Python equivalent for the above will be :

```
command = f"""cqlsh {host} -u {username} -p '{password}' -k '{db_name}' -e \" COPY played_logs FROM '{file_path}' WITH DELIMITER = ','; \" """
```

Then by using the `os` module simply pass the command to shell :

```
os.system(command)
```